# System.OutOfMemoryException как обойти?

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

На данный момент в коде в 2-х местах встречаются подобные исключения, т.е. как я понимаю не хватает оперативной памяти. Тогда как использовать в добавок к оперативке файл подкачки?

Или возможно есть еще какие либо варианты?

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

string[] path_xlsx = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(tmp_folder);

                foreach (string path in path_xlsx)
                {
                    if (path != "")
                    {

                        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(out_folder))
                        {
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(out_folder);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.IO.Directory.Delete(out_folder, true);
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(out_folder);
                        }

                        string[] source_path = path.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                        string source_path_str = source_path[source_path.Length - 1];

                        string[] path_str = source_path_str.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                        string sheet_name = path_str[0];

                        string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

                        string[] full_file = file.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                        string file_xlsx = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\shablon.xlsx";

                        //Создаем workbook
                        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();

                        //Название страницы
                        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheet_name);

                        var rngTable = worksheet.Range("A1:J1");
                        var rngHeaders = rngTable.Range("A1:J1");
                        rngHeaders.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                        rngHeaders.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        rngHeaders.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Orange;
                        rngHeaders.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.WarmBlack;

                        worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Модель мотоцикла";
                        worksheet.Cell("B1").Value = "Дата продажи";
                        worksheet.Cell("C1").Value = "Лот мотоцикла";
                        worksheet.Cell("D1").Value = "Номер рамы";
                        worksheet.Cell("E1").Value = "Объем двигателя";
                        worksheet.Cell("F1").Value = "Цвет";
                        worksheet.Cell("G1").Value = "Год";
                        worksheet.Cell("H1").Value = "Пробег, км.";
                        worksheet.Cell("I1").Value = "Оценка";
                        worksheet.Cell("J1").Value = "Цена, йен";
                        worksheet.Range("A1:J1");

                        int count_lines = 0;

                        for (int i = 2; i <= full_file.Length; i++)
                        {

                            string[] val = full_file[count_lines].Split(new string[] { "&&&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                            string date_prod = val[0];
                            string model = val[1];
                            string lot = val[2];
                            string rama = val[3];
                            string obyom = val[4];
                            string cvet = val[5];
                            string reg_year = val[6];
                            string probeg = val[7];
                            string ocenca = val[8];
                            string cena = val[9];

                            worksheet.Cell("A" + i).Value = model;
                            worksheet.Cell("B" + i).Value = date_prod;
                            worksheet.Cell("C" + i).Value = lot;
                            worksheet.Cell("D" + i).Value = rama;
                            worksheet.Cell("E" + i).Value = obyom;
                            worksheet.Cell("F" + i).Value = cvet;
                            worksheet.Cell("G" + i).Value = reg_year;
                            worksheet.Cell("H" + i).Value = probeg;
                            worksheet.Cell("I" + i).Value = ocenca;
                            worksheet.Cell("J" + i).Value = cena;

                            count_lines++;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            workbook.SaveAs(out_folder + sheet_name + ".xlsx");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }

                    }
                }

                button1.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = true;
                button4.Enabled = true;
                button5.Enabled = true;
                numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;
                label10.Text = "Все готово!";

            }
```

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске, хрустальный шар разбит, кофейная гуща вылита.
Покажите код.

Comment: Код длинный, не хотел выкладывать. Ошибку выдает в блоке try catch

Comment: `XLWorkbook` — [это `IDisposable`](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/78666#1045380). Соответственно, попробуйте использовать конструкцию `using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())`.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, жрет все так же порядка 1.5 гигов ОЗУ и не сохраняет с той же ошибкой.

Comment: Видимо простые способы не работают. Меняйте алгоритм.

Comment: Придется так поступить. Спасибо.

Comment: @z668

- На самом деле лично я в вашем коде (если правильно использовать `using`), не вижу ничего такого, что могло бы приводить к `unbounded memory usage`. Утекает ли память, если не вызывать `SaveAs`? Можете ли вы пройтись `Memory Profiler'ом` и посмотреть, какие объекты занимают весь `heap` в момент, когда происходит `OutOfMemoryException`?

- `ClosedXML` как библиотека выглядит довольно сырой и не слишком качественно написанной. Попробуйте использовать какие-нибудь альтернативы, например, `OpenXML SDK.`[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd452407(v=office.12).aspx]

Comment: А какой размер файла? И зачем Вы его целиком в память загоняете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем либа ClosedXML сырая. Использую Aspose.Cells, все идеально, 400000 строк в лист записываются за минуту отжирая при этом всего лишь 250МБ ОЗУ. Вот только стоит Aspose.Cells порядка 1000$. Пока что она работает, но вставляет новый лист с копирайтами, подумываю его просто вырезать другой либой.

Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А может лучше свою эффективную реализацию XML написать?

--

Хотя, XML в принципе, дурь. И, возможно, тратить на это время и вообще связываться с этим форматом не стоит.

Comment: "А может лучше свою эффективную реализацию XML написать?" - было бы неплохо, вот только ее поддерживать, нужно. Если к примеру Aspose.Cells.dll команда делала, то одному потянуть и поддерживать проект сложно.
"Хотя, XML в принципе, дурь. И, возможно, тратить на это время и вообще связываться с этим форматом не стоит." - абсолютно согласен, вот только других шустрых вариантов для работы с xlsx на данный момент я незнаю. Ну и офисные работники привыкли до чертиков к Excel-лю, да и особо то нет вариантов.

Comment: Зря. Вы бы заставили начальство/заказчика _купить_ для вас библиотеку — вы же не хотите иметь проблемы с законом, если что? (Не сказать заказчику, что в проекте взломанная библиотека — подстава.)

Comment: > было бы неплохо, вот только ее поддерживать, нужно

Не нужно.

Comment: @VladD заказчику софт предоставляется без исходников, софт необходим только 1 заказчику, так что в массы он не пойдет в любом случае. Еслибы были необходимы исходники я бы поступил так как Вы и написали.

@Flammable тогда было бы отлично. Из 3-х либ, с помощью которых удобно работать с xlsx файлами 2-ве оказались крайне прожорливыми, этот момент тоже стоит учесть.

Comment: @z668: А что это меняет? Или вы не нарушаете закон только под угрозой немедленной посадки?

Comment: @VladD В России все нарушают закон, взгляните к примеру на свой ПК - я уверен что на нем часть (если не все) ПО - пиратское. Да и отдел "К" как правило не владеет Рефлектором, им проще студентов за установку "Винды и офиса" ловить. Захотят покрупнее - то Автокад, 1с, фотошопы, корелы и т.д.

Comment: @z668: Я живу в Германии; здесь, хотя обычно и закрывают глаза на использование пиратского ПО домашними пользователями, жёстко преследуют пиратство со стороны бизнеса. (На компьютере, с которого я пишу, пиратского ПО нету.)

Оправданий тому, чтобы не заставить клиента заплатить за хорошую библиотеку, которую я использую в его проекте, не вижу. Тем более, если купленная библиотека уничтожит данные пользователя, производитель будет официально виноват, а если взломанная?

Comment: @VladD Я понимаю Вас с вашей стороны, поймите и Вы меня, Россия есть Россия, только крпные проекты позволят себе оплачивать либы дот нета, если я включу стоимость либы в проект заказчик мягко говоря "удивится", софт столько не стоит сколько эта либа)

Comment: @Alexis, OpenXML самого по себе вполне хватает для создания xlsx. Можно и без лишних библиотек обойтись.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ту задачу давно уже выполнил. Из тех либ что были представлены - Aspose получилась самая оптимизированная.